# Springboot - Getting null pointer on NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a @repository class where I am using :

```
@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;
```

and defining datasource in application.properties. However, when method runs it thrown null pointer exception on line

`template.update(INSERT_SQL_USER, parameters);`

saying template is run. shouldn't springboot automatically bind datasource with the template? how can I resolve this issue?

p.s. I am using MySQL database

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more information about the code snippet to better understand.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.